# Tag UISwitches in UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I Have a UITableView and I put a UISwitch in every UITableViewCell (Static Cells).
Every UISwitch sends a command to a web page and the problem is that all the UISwitches I put in the UITableView send just the command that sends the first UISwitch.

I know that if the UISwitches were created programmatically, the code to solve my problem was `theSwitch.tag = indexPath.row`, but, how can I do the same with UISwitches created in the storyboard?

I Hope You'll Help Me.

Regards.

Comment: Nothing about your code makes much sense. What are `relay1` - `relay4` and why do you set their targets over and over for every cell request? Why do you have four switch ivars (`firstSwitch`, `secondSwitch`, etc.)? Why do you create those `UISwitch` objects but don't set them up in any way?

Comment: That's even more confusing. Edit your question with the actual code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a UISwitch, by code you need:

```
// Create
UISwitch *firstSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
// Add its action
[firstSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(selectorTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// If you have several with the same action, you can use tag.
firstSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;
// And finally added to the view.
cell.accessoryView = firstSwitch;
```

// The complete method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"rIden";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    UISwitch *theSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    // You can put here the action you want.
    cell.accessoryView = theSwitch;
}
// And here
cell.textLabel.text = @"The name...";
UISwitch *theSwitchUsedInThisCell = (UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView;
theSwitchUsedInThisCell.tag = indexPath.row;


return cell;
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to add these in cellForRowAtIndexPath....instead her should subclass UITableViewCell and add it inside interface builder

Comment: why not ? what´s the problem ?

Comment: You don't have to make a new switch each time. Due to cell reuse, there may already be a switch set as the accessory view that can be reused.

Comment: For the reasons @CrimsonChris listed. Generally you want cellForRowAtIndexPath to be as lightweight as possible, which discourages adding subviews to a cell. It's just called so dang much

Comment: @JayMorgan There isn't a difference in performance between adding subviews manually vs using custom subclasses. The performance hit occurs when recreating subviews that have already been created (thanks to cell reuse).

Comment: JayMorgan and @CrimsonChris I complete my answer with a methods by example. Please let me know what´s the performance problem. Best

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like subclassing UITableViewCell, then you can use the accessoryView to show your switches.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UISwitch *switchView = cell.accessoryView ?: [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchWasToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.accessoryView = switchView;
    return cell;
}

- (void)switchWasToggled:(UISwitch *)switchView {
    CGRect switchFrame = [switchView convertRect:switchView.bounds toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:switchFrame.origin];
    [self setOn:(BOOL)isOn atIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)setOn:(BOOL)isOn atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Switch number %d is %@", indexpath.row, isOn ? @"on" : @"off"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [web loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```